# Programmatically Code a UITableView for iPhone Application in Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios5

I have been working in Storyboards for a while now and they are perfect for smaller apps. But I'm trying to put together a collection of 40+ recipes so it's unrealistic for me to drag 40 different Detail Views onto the Storyboard!

I'm wondering how can I programmatically build a table view with 40 different rows that each lead to the same Detail View, but pull different content? Thinking of storing the content in an array and based on which table cell the user clicks we pull from a different index in the array. So for example if the user clicks on recipe #2 in the table it will load a generic Detail View which populates its data from my array index #2.. Please ask for clarification if I'm not making any sense.

I've looked through the Apple docs and a lot of their tutorials reference Core Data which I would like to not use... I don't think it's required for iOS 5 and there must be an easier way than using Storyboard to drag-and-drop 40 different Detail Scenes.

Comment: the situation you describe is really basic, and is described in almost every tutorial about table views on ios

Comment: You should consider putting the data you wish to display in a property list, and loading it dynamically.

Comment: @Vince yes I just went through [this one](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/ios/introduction-to-the-ios-uitableviewcontroller/) and it doesn't exactly clarify how to populate the table content. Also It's difficult to find a newer tut dealing with Xcode's new interface - though I know the code should be very similar.

Comment: @AlexNichol That sounds like exactly what I'm trying to do but have no idea how! Do you have any online tutorials or guides or something I could follow?

Comment: i suggest you take a look at this [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is at a very high level so I can't provide much help other than to provide guidance.  Your idea in the second paragraph sounds exactly how you should write your application in iOS.

1. You build a model containing your recipes (CoreData or other store)
2. Link this to a navigation controller hosting a table view controller (NSFetchedResults controller or your own code or a combination of both)
3. A selection in the table view pushes the (generic) detail view controller onto the Navigation stack (using the push segue is probably easiest)
4. The detail view controller populates itself (with the detailed recipe instructions) using a unique name that you pass to it that will enable it to load the detailed recipe from your data store

In fact, I believe that Apple demoed an example app that did exactly this during either WWDC
2010 or WWDC 2011.

If there's any section you are not clear on, post a new question detailing what the problem is, what you've tried so far and/or what your errors are.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah I'm still really new to Xcode so it's the language that causes a lot of confusion. How would I construct a model of recipes, just make an array variable? And where would this code be placed - possibly in MasterViewController.m? I don't have much completed now just a basic Master View Template in Xcode - I had buttons working to segue between different views except these are ugly and certainly not practical for navigation.

Comment: There are many different ways of creating a model.  Arrays are a common method as is Core Data.  If you're new to iOS then start with arrays; it's less convenient but a much less steep learning curve.  Try Core Data later after you understand the tableview pattern and how it works.  To navigate from a table view cell (or any object that accepts touches) to a detail view controller just control-drag from the cell to the detail view in the Storyboard and choose "push".  No extra buttons needed.  In general, start simple and build the app up to your vision.

Comment: Awesome man I appreciate this. I got my table view running but the main issue I'm hitting is that I can only display 1 String from the Array. I [posted a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705959/uitableview-numberofrowsinsection-will-not-load-more-than-one-row) if you can check out the code I'd love your feedback