# UITableView numberOfRowsInSection Will Not Load More than One Row

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

So I have a UITableView which should loop through a single NSMutableArray and use each of them as row labels. Currently the only way I can get this to run is with 0 or 1 rows, 2 or higher throws out an error saying the array index is off. I tried NSLog to output my array and can confirm it's reading all the Strings.

```
// table methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2;
} 

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

// Set up the cell...
NSString *cellValue = [harvestRecipeList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

return cell;
}
```

The array code is stored in the exact same file (MasterViewController.m) which I added below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    harvestRecipeList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [harvestRecipeList addObject:@"Ice Cream"];
    [harvestRecipeList addObject:@"Walnut Cake"];
    [harvestRecipeList addObject:@"Cookies"];
    [harvestRecipeList addObject:@"Salad"];
    [harvestRecipeList addObject:@"Grilled Fish"];

    //Set the title
    self.navigationItem.title = @"BTN Recipes";
}
```

I would love any help on this it's been bugging me. I was using *[harvestRecipeList count]* but this throws the same array index error. And as I mentioned I can get the app to run perfectly fine with 0 or 1 rows - thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: here is the error I'm getting in the output window after building:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

**EDIT2**: included below my property setup for harvestRecipeList

```
//MasterViewController.h
@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *harvestRecipeList;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *harvestRecipeList;

// and also my MasterViewController.m 
@synthesize harvestRecipeList;
```

**EDIT3**
here's my source code zipped for this project. It's called treehouse, just a testing name for now but you can [dl from my cloudapp here](http://cl.ly/D1ot).

Comment: Please post which error you are receiving. There is surely something wrong if sending `-count` to an instance of `NSMutableArray` is throwing an error.

Comment: Have you tried `NSLog`-ing your `harvestRecipeList` before querying an object? To make sure it contains the right elements?

Comment: @MarkAdams yes sure thing I'm adding the error to my original post. I can't make much sense of it and have been googling for about an hour now...

Comment: @lef2 yes I did output the whole array and all 5 data values came out. plus I changed [harvestRecipeList count] to a formatted string and this output the numeral 5

Comment: @JakeRocheleau Have you tried using self.harvestRecipeList instead?

Comment: @ThomasHajcak yes it's very strange, they both return the same values in NSLog. And no matter if I use self.harvestRecipeList or just harvestRecipeList I always get the NSRangeException error.

Comment: Okay, if your log message display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I examined the code you put in the `ZIP` file. I immediately noticed your using the iOS 5 Storyboard feature. I haven't got Xcode 4 nor the iOS 5 SDK, so I could not test that part of your application.

However, I went on and coded your Storyboard part by hand. I have tested your `MasterViewController` solely and found no errors. I added in the `AppDelegate` this method to replace the Storyboard automatical features and just show the view controller where you think the error is coming from.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    MasterViewController *myVC;
    _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:
               [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    myVC = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [_window setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
    [_window addSubview:myVC.view];

    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

To prove your `MasterViewController.m` contains no error, I add this screenshot:

[image]

**Conclusion:** Your error is to be found somewhere else, probably in your Storyboard file. However I have never used that new functionality so I cannot help you with that. I suggest you review your Storyboard and put all attention to that file.

Comment: thanks man you went above and beyond! Appreciate all your time and patience I'll have to check it out further.

Comment: I've tested the code and the issue is in the Storyboard.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

```
Updated Solution:
```

So I have checked your code and found the problem.  Do the following:

1. Go into your storyboard and select the Master Table View (click where it says Static Content)
2. Click on the Attributes Inspector (looks like a downward arrow sort of) and change the content from `Static Cells` to `Dynamic Prototypes`
3. Click on the prototype cell and type `Cell` into Identifier field (this is what you are using as a cell ID
4. Also change the Accessory from `None` to `Disclosure Indicator`
5. In your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` return `self.harvestRecipeList.count`
6. In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you can remove the following two lines (as they are provided by the Storyboard):

   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
7. Recreate your Push segue from your Master Cell to your Detail View Controller

It should all now work fine - and I've tested that it works.  The basic problem was you had specified Static Cells rather than Dynamic Prototypes and the rest of the instructions are just mopping up.  The NSRangeException was caused by only having a single cell so that was all that was displayed.

Hope this helps.

```
Previous Solution:
```

So, a few comments but, first, if you've updated your code can you post an update?

1. Your `harvestRecipeList` that you add objects to in `ViewDidLoad` does not appear to be the same `harvestRecipeList` that you synthesised - it will be local to the method so your instance variable will always be nil.  You should always use `self.harvestRecipeList` - do this everywhere.  This could easily explain your `NSRangeException`.  Also see #4 below.
2. In your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` you should return `self.harvestRecipeList.count`
3. If you are using the iOS5 SDK, you do not need to check if `cell == nil` as `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` is guaranteed to return non-nil cell.  You do need to check if you are on the iOS4 SDK.
4. Change your `@synthesize harvestRecipeList;` to `@synthesize harvestRecipeList = _harvestRecipeList;` as this will assist with #1 and checking you are accessing the ivar.

Try `#1` & `#2` as a minimum and then post an update on the problems you are having.  Hope this helps.

Comment: If find your statement 'You should always use `self.harvestRecipeList` ' a bit subjective. If a developer likes to set its private instance variables directly, why **should/must** you use properties? I find that a personal choice.

Comment: Sigh.  Experienced iOS developers can easily understand the difference between the private ivar and the properties but new iOS developers do not.  This answer is for a new iOS developer and so I am trying to keep my answer simple and easily understood rather than confusing the issue with details that are irrelevant to the question at hand.  I'm trying to solve this problem to assist someone not confuse them and not solve their problem.

Comment: @RoboticCat hey thanks I see you found my link. I tried updating the synthesize code with what you posted, and also changed all references to self.harvestRecipeList. The problem doesn't seem to be that the list is empty - at least, I can output the array as a string in NSLog. But when the app compiles I only get 1 row of data, any more and I get the NSRangeException posted above. I'll share my source code if that may help as well... *EDIT* just added a link to my original post at the top!

Comment: Thanks Robotic. It works for my problem which is the problem caused by the static cell. Thanks a lot, great post.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, if your log messages display an array with five objects right before you try to query the second, and you application gives you an `NSRangeException` the bug is definitely not to be found in the code you show us.

Try to find it by placing various logs before and after any `-[NSArray objectAtIndex:]` and see which log doesn't come through after the call. There's your error.

Remember you can use

```
NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
```

to show where you log message is coming from. Their also exists a line and file macro, but normally the function macro should help you enough.

**Example:**

```
NSLog(@"%s Before", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
[myArray objectAtIndex:anIndex];
NSLog(@"%s After", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
```

If your second log message doesn't come through, then you'll have found your error.

Comment: Thank you I truly didn't even know where to start... adding the NSLog both before & after my objectAtIndex method returned an error "EXEC_BAD_ACCESS" - here's [my screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/PLc7Z.png) from within Xcode if that helps at all?

Comment: Interestingly enough I tried deleting the first __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ and replaced it with self.harvestRecipeList. This outputs my array just fine, and on the 2nd NSLog I still get the same error. Here's [another screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/6Y51o.png) if this helps at all.

Comment: @JakeRocheleau My bad, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is of type `const char *`. The correct way to use it is with the `%s` flag. I edited my original answer. Secondly it's not a surprise your array gets printed out. When you use `NSLog` with the `%@` flag, `NSLog` excpects an `NSString`. If you pass an other object, `NSLog` will call `-description` on the passed object. This method returns a string representation of the object.

Comment: Okay that makes more sense thanks for the edits! With my `numberOfRowsInSection` set to 1 the code compiles fine and I get [this output](http://cl.ly/D2ZI). I hope this provides something useful? the name of the app is treehouse just to clarify.. and when I try setting the rows to `self.harvestRecipeList.count` I don't get any output other than the regular compiler error( [screenshot](http://cl.ly/D1ut) )

Comment: also check my edit in the first post above, I included a .zip with my source code. I'm hoping this would be easier in figuring out why I can only generate 1 row out... rather than me explaining with my limited knowledge over the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

It is always best to use the setter and getter methods for your instance variables. It takes care of a lot of problems. My guess is that is your problem. So anywhere you want to use `harvestRecipeList` use `self.harvestRecipeList` 
It would be useful to know what your property declaration is for harvestRecipeList

Comment: hey absolutely! I added the code to my main post above since I can't use it in reply comments... please let me know if this helps at all.